# how can i reduce the number of entries in my database to use some classification algorithms like SVM or kNN in R?

Tags: r, svm, adaboost

i have this database from using the Emotiv Epoc in volunteers, so i need to run some classification algorithms to analyze if there is a difference between men and women. The problem here: I need to use algorithms like kNN, SVM, penalyzedSVM, decision tree, Naive Bayes, adaboost, etc, but to run this on the database. I need less entries. 
The database is like this:

http://imageshack.com/a/img922/4035/gU165e.png

So, for each volunteer, i have around 600 entries per test. And 50 volunteers, 25/25   Male/Female.
Anybody here know what can i do to reduce the number of entries, or which algorithms can i use?

Pleas help me.

Comment: Go for running PCA first

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the `unique` command. I note that for each entry your data differ, which is a factor that you should also take into account. However, you can keep one entry for each individual in this way:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
dt <-data.table(a,b)

>dt
      a    b
1:    A    1
2:    A    1
3:    A    2
4:    B    4
5:    B    1
6:    B    1
7:    C    2
8:    C    2

>unique(dt,by="a")
      a    b
1:    A    1
2:    B    4
3:    C    2
```

Hope that answers what you want!